# Using linear regression model, fear of crime as a function of "state" and "trait anxiety" or both state & trait anxiety?

Tags: r

```
Library(readr)
crime_replication <- read_csv("crime_replciation.csv")
head(crime_replication)
```

need suggestion which formula should be used to find the solution....

I tried the code(still not confirmed), and i am looking for the formula?

Comment: See `?lm` - Something like `lm(Y ~ X1 * X2, data = mydata)`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It helps reproduce the problem when the post includes a data set.
An effective way to include one is `dput()`.
Run dput, then paste the output into your question.
See [rdocumentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/dput).
If your object is a vector, matrix, table, or data frame and is large,
`object |> head() |> dput()` will help give manageably sized output.